# Persistent storage to store one set of key-value pairs in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift2, realm, persistent-storage

I want persistent storage(persistent across views) for my app, I came across Realm, but now I think its just too heavy for what I am trying to do.

Basically I have data in JSON format(which I fetch every time the app starts, I want to store it in a variable(in a Dictionary) so I can access it from different screens of my iPad app. (I also don't care if the data gets lost when the app is closed, I just want the data to be available across different screens(views) of my app when app is running)

Example Data

```
{
    "pid": 23,
    "name": "some name",
    "cities": [ {
                  "id": 1,
                  "name": "Bangalore"
                },
                {
                  "id": 2,
                  "name": "Mysore"
                }
                { //continues for about 100 more city entries
                }
              ],
    "hospital": {
                  "id": 234, 
                  "name": "newHorizon", 
                  "type": "nursing home"
                }
}
```

Is Realm a suitable option for this? If yes, how do I fetch say `hospital->name` from my example data?

If not, what kind of storage is suitable in this case?

I am looking for ios equivalent for `localStorage` of Javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realm persists data even when application is not active. I guess that you do not care. I would advise to create a session object (a singleton object) with a `Dictionary` as one of the data property.

Convert your JSON into Dictionary and save it in your singleton session object. Fetch it like `myData["Hospital"]["name"]`

**EDIT:** On OP request

**Step 1:** Setting up singleton

```
//
//  MySession.swift
//

import Foundation

class MySession {

    static let sharedInstance = MySession()

    var myData = Dictionary<String,AnyObject>()
}
```

**Step 2:** Save data in singleton in class 1

```
var dict = Dictionary<String,AnyObject>()
dict["pid"] = "123"
dict["hospital"] = ["id":"234", "name":"newHorizon", "type":"nursing home"]

MySession.sharedInstance.myData = dict
```

**Step 3:** Fetch saved data in class 2

```
let myData = MySession.sharedInstance.myData as Dictionary
let hospitalDict = myData["hospital"]


if let name = hospitalDict?["name"] as? String {
    print(name)
}
```

Comment: How do I create a singleton session object in Swift2?

Comment: Thanks Abhinav! Works as expected.

Comment: I think I should add a getter and setter methods to MySession class.

Comment: You can do that. If your data is more or less generic than why now. Go ahead and explore new dimensions :)!

Comment: Correction - I meant then why not :-)